# Comparing dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

Given two dictionaries, `d1` and `d2`, and an integer `l`, I want to find all keys `k` in `d1` such that either `d2[k]<l` or `k not in l`. I want to output the keys and the corresponding values in `d2`, except if `d2` does not contain the key, I want to print 0. For instance, if `d1` is

```
a: 1
b: 1
c: 1
d: 1
```

and `d2` is

```
a: 90
b: 89
x: 45
d: 90
```

and `l` is 90, the output would be (possibly in a different order)

```
b 89
c 0
```

What is the best way to do this in Python? I am just starting to learn the language, and so far this is what I have:

```
for k in d1.keys():
    if k not in d2:
        print k, 0
    else:
        if d2[k]<l:
            print k, d2[k]
```

This works of course (unless I have a typo), but it seems to me that there would be a more pythonic way of doing it.

Comment: In the first paragraph do you mean "k not in d2" instead of "k not in l"?

Answer (score 10):

Yours is actually fine -- you could simplify it to

```
for k in d1:
    if d2.get(k, 0) < l:
       print k, d2.get(k, 0)
```

which is (to me) pythonic, and is pretty much a direct "translation" into code of your description.

If you want to avoid the double lookup, you could do

```
for k in d1:
    val = d2.get(k, 0)
    if val < l:
        print k, val
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simplify this by using a defaultdict. Calling __getitem__ on a defaultdict will return the "default" value.

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int)
print d['this key does not exist'] # will print 0
```

Another bit that you could change is not to call keys. The dictionary implements **iter**. It would be preferable to simply write:

```
for k in d1:
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a compact version, but yours is perfectly OK:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1, 'd': 1}
d2 = {'a': 90, 'b': 89, 'x': 45, 'd': 90}
l = 90

# The default (==0) is a substitute for the condition "not in d2"
# As daniel suggested, it would be better if d2 itself was a defaultdict
d3 = defaultdict(int, d2)
print [ (k, d3[k]) for k in d1 if d3[k] < l ]
```

Output:

```
[('c', 0), ('b', 89)]
```

Comment: This is really a +1 for daniel

Answer (score 0):

Yours is good enough but here's one that is a little simpler:

```
for k in d1:
    val = d2.get(k, 0)
    
    if val < l:
        print k, val
```